# Why are stm32 addresses larger than flash size?

Tags: stm32, flash

I am a complete beginner to using STM32 boards. I bought an STM32F103C8T6 board, and the product page said it has `128 KB` of memory. I am using Linux and am using [this](https://github.com/stlink-org/stlink) open source `stlink` toolchain (of which the `st-link` and `st-flash` tools I have used below are a part) and a cheap STLinkV2 clone programmer.

```
$ st-link --flash
0x20000
```

Clearly it identifies the flash size correctly as `0x20000` (or 128 KiB in decimal) as expected. But what I cannot understand is why every reference I find on programming these boards uses addresses that are way larger than this value. To be more specific, many references I have found online seem to use `0x8000000` as a starting address for writing to the flash, such as the manpage for the `st-flash` tool which is used to program the STM32 flash:

```
EXAMPLES
       Flash firmware.bin to device

              $ st-flash write firmware.bin 0x8000000

       Read firmware from device (4096 bytes)

              $ st-flash read firmware.bin 0x8000000 0x1000

       Erase firmware from device

              $ st-flash erase
```

I ran the command:

```
$ st-flash write firmware.bin 0x8000000
```

and it worked! when I used the more intuitive starting address of `0x0` it **failed**:

```
$ st-flash write firmware.bin 0x0
```

Can someone explain how this makes sense.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's a 32-bit MCU with a 32-bit address space. You may have only 128 KB of flash and a few kilobytes of RAM and a few hundred or few thousand of peripheral registers, but they have to live somewhere in the 4 gigabyte address space.

The flash is at the address that starts at 0x08000000. RAM starts at 0x20000000. The MCU starts running code at address 0, but it only works because you have to select how the memory is mapped when the MCU starts, and under normal use the flash is mapped to 0, and in some other cases the RAM or factory bootloader system memory is mapped to 0.

Comment: By the way, that is utterly usual in computers of all sizes. From the earliest computers with an actual memory bus to your PC: memory space is typically not the same as physical memory.

Comment: You can even have more physical memory than address space, either by banking, or by virtual mapping (32 bit userspaces on 64 bit supervisors was a not unusual arrangement in the early days of x64 processors)

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the datasheet of the [STM32F103C8T6 device](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f103c8.pdf), it shows the base address of the Flash memory as 0x0800 0000.  Refer to Figure 11 in section 4 *Memory Mapping*.  This is the reason you need to use a minimum address of 0x0800 0000 to access the Flash.

This device has 32 bits of addressable memory space.

Address 0 is described as:

> Aliased to flash or system memory depending on BOOT pins

In this case, address 0 will not access the Flash.

Answer (score 5):

Being asked on a hardware site, understand that you have the ARM processor address space that is divided down depending on the core into buses on the edge of the ARM [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_property).  Then the chip folks take over from there (ST), and interface to and decode on each bus, and map, within the rules for the core, the rest of address world.

The flash itself is one or more modules that have their own, zero based, address space.  The [SRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random-access_memory) is the same story.  Your glue logic takes some ARM address space that then may be boiled down into some sub-space, and then you map that by removing more upper address bits into the flash or SRAM module addresses with enables generated by the upper addresses you removed.

Think about looking out the front door of your house, and you can see the tree outside.  Now move over a few feet to the first window, and you can also see the tree, but you are now say 7 feet from the wall. The door was zero feet from the wall.  Now move over a bit more, say 12 feet from the wall and you can see the same tree.   The flash itself can be and as documented is when certain inputs are configured a certain way, mapped in two different places.  The ARM core requires that on reset it reads from the vector table which is documented as a chip vendor configured address, (if that was not zero then the users would come unglued), so in some way they fake (mirror) that access to be through a different window, that can still see the same tree (the flash).

The next step is on you. Did you link your application to be 0x00000000 based or 0x08000000 based?  If the reset vector is 0x00000000 based, then the chip will operate, and your flash window at address zero is not assumed to be able to see all of the flash (too narrow to see the whole tree), but it will operate within whatever size that window is (I am not sure if that is documented).  The proper solution for this chip (not an ARM thing, but an STM32xyz thing) is to link for 0x08000000, and then that first reset vector scoots us down to the bigger window and we can see all of the flash and operate directly from that point on independent of the mirror settings, in some (STM32xyz) chips, if not all, being able to then change that zero based window if so desired.

Now you get into programming the device, if you are using a [Nucleo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32#Nucleo_boards) or other that has a debug MCU and the target MCU and the debug MCU provides a fake thumb drive on your development computer that you can then drag and drop a binary into and have the debug MCU program the target MCU and reset it.  Most and certainly older versions of that firmware allow for zero-based or 0x08000000 based, newer as I am seeing (and note a good idea to update the firmware on a Nucleo the first thing you do although finding that little Java tool can be a challenge, one size fits all tool, connects to ST to find the latest version for the thing you are running it against).  That firmware, or of course other tools, can easily look at the addresses in the vector table, at least the reset address and see if it is zero-based or not and decide if it wants to proceed, perhaps the user dropped the wrong format file down and this is simply going to crash/hang the MCU as soon as reset is released.

When a chip vendor buys IP like this that has a rule or convention of a fixed address like zero, and one might want multiple boot options, including an on chip factory bootloader, then they generally want/need a mirroring scheme to go along with that desire.  Other ways to do it with ARM cores, but...So a couple of vendors that have been doing factory bootloaders continue to do this with their [Cortex-M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M) based products.  But with [SWD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTAG#Similar_interface_standards) between only needing two pins and the availability of affordable tools, a number of Cortex-M-based products from other vendors do not have this mirror, and you build for 0x00000000.  And note for the ones that do mirror, each vendor has its own mirror address; it is not an ARM thing.  And even within the STM32 world, there is the 0x08000000 that so far all of them support and I have touched many of their parts.  But some now support 0x00200000 and for some of those that is the preferred address due to bus speed.

ARM dictated some broad addressing rules for Cortex-M parts, so that is why you see 0x20000000 for the start of SRAM and peripherals at like 0x40000000 and execution space below 0x20000000, on some you see an SRAM mirror below 0x20000000.

---

For this part, you want to link your binary to 0x08000000 and load at 0x08000000 and limit the size of the loadable binary to be within the size of the flash.  There are exceptions to this that work just fine. If you are using a [Blue Pill](https://stm32-base.org/boards/STM32F103C8T6-Blue-Pill.html) for example you can use the UART to talk to the on chip bootloader and load to SRAM and boot from SRAM or link for 0x00000000 and load that into flash (or use SWD and do the above as well).   Your easiest user experience though is to link for 0x08000000 and limit the linker to the size of the flash or smaller, and the tools in general should be happy.  And your experience should be less of a struggle.

Answer (score 2):

The ARM core uses a 32-bit ALU to compute addresses, but that doesn't mean that there are 4 billion circuits associated with addressing.  It's pretty simple to have a circuit to detect whether all of the address bits within a range are clear, and then e.g. have a circuit force an address trap if the upper four address bits are 0100, and any of address bits in the range 17-27 aren't clear, so decoding the entire address space doesn't really cost much.

A technique which some ARM devices use to allow the interrupt vector table to be kept in RAM even though the first two words are used as the interrupt vector, which has to be in ROM, is to have three decoded address ranges:

- 40000000-40003FFF : 16K of RAM
- 08000000-0801FFFF : 128K of flash
- 00000000-01FFFFFF : Behave like one of the above ranges, based upon the state of a control register bit.

This approach is simpler and cheaper than allowing the interrupt vector table to use an arbitrary address.  I don't know offhand whether it's used by any STM parts in particular, but I know I've used parts that work that way.